# Adding multiple XML elements/containers dynamically using XML MarkupBuilder in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, markupbuilder

I am trying to generate XML using Groovy MarkupBuilder.

XML needed is of this form (simplified):

```
<Order>
  <StoreID />
  <City />
  <Items>
    <Item>
      <ItemCode />
      <UnitPrice />
      <Quantity />
    </Item>
  </Items>
</Order>
```

The data is stored in an Excel file and is easily accessible. My Groovy script parses the Excel and generates the XML.

e.g.

```
import groovy.xml.*
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

xml.Order{
  StoreID("Store1")
  City("New York")
  Items(){
    Item(){
      ItemCode("LED_TV")
      UnitPrice("800.00")
      Quantity("2")
    }
  }
}
```

There can be multiple "item" containers inside "items".

My question is: 
Let's say we want to generate Order XML having 10 items. Is there a way to write something like a for loop inside "items" container? That way, we won't need to write MarkupBuilder code for 10 different items.

There is a similar question [Adding dynamic elements and attributes to groovy MarkupBuilder or StreamingMarkupBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789738/adding-dynamic-elements-and-attributes-to-groovy-markupbuilder-or-streamingmarku). But it doesn't discuss looping.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes there is a way of using loop. Extending your example here:

```
import groovy.xml.*
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

//List of items represented as a map
def items = [[itemCode: "A", unitPrice: 10, quantity: 2], 
             [itemCode: "B", unitPrice: 20, quantity: 3], 
             [itemCode: "C", unitPrice: 30, quantity: 4], 
             [itemCode: "D", unitPrice: 40, quantity: 6], 
             [itemCode: "E", unitPrice: 50, quantity: 5]]

xml.Order{
  StoreID("Store1")
  City("New York")
  Items{
    //Loop through the list.
    //make sure you are using a variable name instead of using "it"
    items.each{item->
      Item{
        ItemCode(item.itemCode)
        UnitPrice(item.unitPrice)
        Quantity(item.quantity)
      }
    }
  }
}

println writer
```

Should give you what you are expecting.

Comment: I see. So we CAN write regular Groovy looping code inside the markup. I thought markup should contain nothing other than markup code. Thanks for the detailed answer. Appreciate it! :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. this helps me lots of effort.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! As a Groovy novice, I searched a lot until I found this!

Answer (score 3):

This contribution has helped me to solve a similar problem : I wanted to call functions in MarkupBuilder blocks, like the `addElement()` function in my example.

I wanted to split the code into different functions.

Example for calling functions in MarkupBuilder blocks :

```
static void addElement(Map<String,String> elements, MarkupBuilder mb) {
    mb."${elements.tag}"(elements.content)
}

static void example() {
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    def htmlBuilder = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

    String tag = "a"
    Map<String, String> attributes1 = new HashMap<>()
    attributes1.put("href","http://address")
    String content1 = "this is a link"

    Map<String, String> element1 = new HashMap<>()
    element1.put("tag","b")
    element1.put("content","bold content 1")

    Map<String, String> element2 = new HashMap<>()
    element2.put("tag","b")
    element2.put("content","bold content 2")

    List<Map<String, String>> elements = new ArrayList<>()
    elements.add(element1)
    elements.add(element2)

    htmlBuilder."html" {
        "${tag}"( attributes1, content1 )
        elements.each { contentIterator ->
            addElement(contentIterator, htmlBuilder)
        }
    }

    println writer
 }
```

and it produces this output :

```
<html>
  <a href='http://address'>this is a link</a>
  <b>bold content 1</b>
  <b>bold content 2</b>
</html>
```